# Add bearer token to AT command

Tags: http, https, gcloud, at-command, sim800

I would like to add Authorization to a request to google cloud.

> **AT commands**

```
Authorization: Bearer [Token]
```

But how do I do this with AT commands?

I'm currently using this:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: Bearer [Token]"
```

But I get a generic AT command error:

```
ERROR\r\n
```

=== Edit ===

So I've drawn closer to the issue

When I put a fake [Token] which is short it works. I get an OK

However, when I use my actual token which is much longer I get Error

Comment: Can you try adding \r\n at the end of the command like this AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Authorization: Bearer [Token]"\r\n

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Sorry, I already do this and still get the error